# How to add flash video in WPF?

Tags: wpf, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one host Flash content in a WPF application and use transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67151/how-can-one-host-flash-content-in-a-wpf-application-and-use-transparency)

How to add flash video in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is an answer  :    [How can one host Flash content in a WPF application and use transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67151/how-can-one-host-flash-content-in-a-wpf-application-and-use-transparency)